# Index + Match Function to multiply a value by a percentage based on a certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to multiply the value in cell `C653` by a value on the "percentages tab" based on whether the value in cell `B869` is FP1, FP2, FP3 ... or FP8.

Imagine you have two tabs, one containing percentages based on the criteria FP1, FP2, FP3 ... all the way to FP8. Each of these criteria have different percentages associated with them in. The percentages to be used in the function lie in cells d4, f4, h4, j4, l4, n4, p4 and r4. On the other tab, you have a value that needs to be multiplied by the given percentage based on the stated criteria of that row (which is in column B)

For whatever reason the formula below is not recognizing cell c653 (which contains the value that needs to be multiplied by the percentage based on the criteria).  Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({C653*percentages!D4,c653*percentages!f4,c653*percentages!h4,c653*percentages!j4,c653*percentages!l4,c653*percentages!n4,c653*percentages!p4,c653*percentages!r4},MATCH($B$869,{FP1,FP2,FP3,FP4,FP5,FP6,FP7,FP8})),0)
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OK, I'll do my best.  Imagine you have two tabs, one containing percentages based on the criteria FP1, FP2, FP3 ... all the way to FP8.  Each of these criteria have different percentages associated with them in.  The percentages to be used in the function lie in calls d4, f4, h4, j4, l4, n4, p4 and r4.  On the other tab, you have a value that needs to be multiplied by the given percentage based on the stated criteria of that row (which is in column B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
=C653*IFERROR(INDEX(percentages!D4:R4,MATCH($B$869,{"FP1","FP2","FP3","FP4","FP5","FP6","FP7","FP8"},0)*2-1),0)
```

I quoted the `FPn` as I gather those are values and not cell references.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
[image: I tried to Replicate your structue.]

Let me know if you need a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not open your link.  Probably because I'm at work and we have firewalls.  If you could explain how you solved the issue that would be great

Comment: **Data Structure for Example**
FP1...FP1 are in cells A1:H1 with corresponding percentages underneath in A2:H2.

**Formula** `=INDEX($A$2:$H$2,1,MATCH($B$869,$A$1:$H$1,0))*C653`

**Desc.** Here, MATCH is returning the position of whatever FPn is in A1:H1.  INDEX then looks in A2:H2 and returns the value in the position identified by MATCH. The resulting value is multiplied by C653.

Comment: I just read your example and noticed the percentages aren't in an array. I'll do my best to try and find another solution.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @zipa's answer above will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more to it than this, but from the information you have provided you are only using the right-hand character of the string FP1 etc. to find the matching percentage so you need to extract this. The percentages are spaced two columns apart so you need to multiply the result by 2 before using INDEX. This would give you

```
=INDEX(percentages!$C$4:$R$4,RIGHT($B$869,1)*2)*$C$653
```